# Excel Power Query: refer to list of aliases within a table?

Tags: excel, powerquery

this is my first question on stackoverflow. Here goes:

Say I have a table that includes four columns. The first three contain email handles from different companies. If the handle in column 1 matches the handles in column 2 or 3, we're good.  Column 3 is sometimes blank. Column 4 is the column that I'm using to let me know if there is a discrepancy. However, certain companies use multiple handles.

For example, a certain company uses @abc.com as well as @xyz.com and @123.com.
For a certain row, column 1 = @xyz.com, Column 2 = @abc.com, Column 3 is blank.

How do I make it so that column 4 lets me know there is no discrepancy for this row?

I was thinking that I could maybe add a (structured?) column that conditionally refers to lists of aliases for columns 2 and 3 for each row, but how do I do that? And how do I add to that list of aliases easily?

Please also assume that I don't have company names. Only the email handles they use.

Thanks!

I've only worked with simple conditional columns so far, and that obviously won't work here.

Comment: Please provide copiable sample data and expected results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A powerquery method:

Create an alias table so that every column on each row will evaluate to a match. Load it into powerquery with table .. from data/range.   Name that query **Alias**.  File .. close and load to ... connection only

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AliasRangeName"]}[Content] in Source
```

Load 3 columns of input data you want to check into powerquery with table .. from data/range. Apply the code below by pasting into home...advanced editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
//replace row above with the autogenerated row when you load the data
Alias2=Table.Buffer(Alias),
check = Table.AddColumn(Source,"Check",  (x)=>
    let a=Table.SelectRows(Alias2, each [Value]=Text.AfterDelimiter(x[Column1],"@")){0}[Index],
    b=try Table.SelectRows(Alias2, each [Value]=Text.AfterDelimiter(x[Column2],"@")){0}[Index] otherwise null,
    c=try Table.SelectRows(Alias2, each [Value]=Text.AfterDelimiter(x[Column3],"@")){0}[Index] otherwise null
    in  if a=b or a=c then "ok" else "bad")
 in check
```

[image]